# Connecting to a DB (Redis) using C once in the program's runtime

Tags: php, c, database, redis

With an `OO` language I often use a factory design pattern to connect to a DB:

```
// Connect to Redis ( PHP )
protected function get_redis() {
   static $redis = false;
   if( $redis === false ) {
      $redis = new Predis\Client(Configure::read('redis.db'));
   }
   return $redis;
}
```

I done quite a lot of `C` but never any big projects.  I want to know how to connect to a Redis DB (or any DB) in C without opening more than one connection.  I know I can use a global variable but is there a better way ?  I don't want to force the factory pattern - it's OO.  Has anyone got any examples ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to disagree with you here. Factory method does not necessarily put an OO stamp on your code. It's just a pattern for creating things.

If you don't want to create more than one connection, you can control that in the `get_connection` function. This is another application for this pattern.